# Creating subdomains in Azure

Tags: azure, subdomain

We have a VM in Azure, ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. I need to create two subdomains, sub1.ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com and sub2.ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. Both must point to the same IP as ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.

How do I do it?

Comment: Hi there, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, Azure does **not** support add subdomains.

If you want to use subdomains, maybe you can **buy a domain name** from domain register(third party, like register.com, godaddy.com), and map your domain name to this VM's Public IP address, then add subdomains to this public IP address.

Comment: For now, Azure does not support subdomains, maybe we can use your own domain name, Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use different port numbers for each website.

Default port: 80  ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Port: 8081    sub1 
Port: 8082    sub2

and Etc.

To access Go to:

http://ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:portNumber

http://ourserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8081 ---> sub1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but MAYBE, the **URL rewrite** can work in this situation.

You can have different folders inside you VM's "public" folder, one for each content of the subdomain. Then, use the URL Rewrite to map each subdmain in their specific folder.

I did something similar, but wasn't for subdomains. I just pointed different domains to different folders. Here is an example of how it would be in your case (I didn't test, just guessed based on my case):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="sub1 virtual path rewrite">
                    <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub1\.ourserver\.westeurope\.cloudapp\.azure$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Sub1Folder/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="sub2 virtual path rewrite">
                    <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub2\.ourserver\.westeurope\.cloudapp\.azure$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Sub2Folder/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="sub1 virtual path rewrite">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://ourserver\.westeurope\.cloudapp\.azure)/Sub1Folder/(.+/)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="sub1/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="sub2 virtual path rewrite">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://ourserver\.westeurope\.cloudapp\.azure)/Sub2Folder/(.+/)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="sub2/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if you will need to create subdomains in the domain register. Maybe you will need to, because sometimes you have to pay extra fees to have subdomains.
So, I don't know if the URL Rewrite would work without creating them. And if it works, I don't know if it's legal to do (please don't do any workaround to avoid the register fees).